# Research: what can I do next if the solution is too long

Tags: optimization, research

Sorry for this vague question. Here is my circumstance: I have tried to formulate a problem with an equation, and it is a optimization problem.

So I just go ahead, and use mathematica to take the derivative of that equation, set it to zero, and solve in terms a variable of interest. The problem I ran into is that it takes 2 min for mathematica to solve it, and the solution (it was an expression) contains 60 lines long.

Obviously, 60 lines long (approx. 1000 mathmatical symbol) will definely not something that can go into a research paper, if the result is to be published.

So I go back to my original problem and tried to see where I can simplify. After some simplification, I repeat and I still got the same result (slightly better actually).

What are the general steps for me to do? What should I do next? Should I approximate the equation or should I approximate the solution?  Or should I just stick with the numerical solution?

Comment: Is there a way to approximate the solution and maintain usefulness?  For example, perhaps the asymptotic performance is interesting enough to warrant publication.  (Just an idea...)

Comment: Maybe I'm confused here, but how is a solution to an optimization problem an expression? Are you solving a "parametric" optimization problem where your solution comes out as a function of some parameters? If you're simply solving an optimization problem the solution to which are numerical values for your variables, then I suggest using more efficient solvers. If you can specify the structure of your problem I might be able to suggest some. Or you can look at the list of solvers at [NEOS](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/) as a starting point.